# Combining metadata and sample information

Tags: r, dataframe, metadata

Example code:

```
sample_8765 <- data.frame(type = c("protein", "mRNA", "mRNA", "mRNA", "protein"),
                          name = c("DIABLO", "X1345", "X1234", "F1234", "p53"),
                          score = c(1.23, 4.265, 3.44, 6.43, 8.00))
sample_8901 <- data.frame(type = c("protein", "mRNA", "protein","mRNA", "protein"),
                          name = c("DIABLO", "X1345", "SMAC", "F4657", "MDM2"),
                          score = c(3.24, 5.33, 4.35, 6.78, 9.11))
sample_9084 <- data.frame(type = c("protein", "protein", "mRNA", "mRNA", "mRNA"),
                          name = c("SMAC", "DIABLO", "X1345", "F4657", "X1234" ),
                          score = c(2.56, 8.11, 4.35, 6.78, 9.11))

sample_ID <- c("sample_8765","sample_8901","sample_9084") #unique samples 
samples <- list(sample_8765,sample_8901,sample_9084)
names(samples)  <- sample_ID
samples <- bind_rows(samples, .id = "sample_ID")

expression <- dcast(samples, name ~ sample_ID, 
                    fun.aggregate = max, value.var = "score" , fill = 0)
#Metadata table
cancer <- c("Yes", "No", "Yes")
metadata <-  data.frame(sample_ID, cancer )
metadata_cancer_Yes <-subset(metadata, cancer == "Yes")
metadata_cancer_No <-subset(metadata, cancer == "No")
```

Hi,

I have created dataframes with information on various samples (like the ones in the example code). I have the metadata for these samples which says whether or not the patients developed cancer (Yes/No). I have subsetted the metadata into Yes/ No cancer status and would like to use this to see if protein and mRNA score differs between these two groups. How would I go about subsetting my samples based on this metadata?

Thanks!

Comment: I get an error which I believe is because you made the "expression" column of class character. (And you really should come up with a different name for that column; `expression` is a commonly used R function. You also should describe in exquisite detail the steps you intend to use on the two subsets of samples. That's not a coding question. It's a domain question in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = merge(samples, metadata)
aggregate(cbind(score = score) ~ cancer + type, data = tmp, FUN = 'mean')

  cancer    type    score
1     No    mRNA 6.055000
2    Yes    mRNA 5.729167
3     No protein 5.566667
4    Yes protein 4.975000
```